# Lipschitz continuity in the second variable

Tags: continuity, definition, lipschitz-functions

In the context of Picard–Lindelöf theorem, one considers a function $f: D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, where $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n$, which is a function of time and space, $f = f(t, y)$. It is assumed that $f$ is continuous in $t$ and Lipschitz continuous in $y$.

It is unclear to me what exactly is meant by Lipschitz continuity in $y$. My intuition would say that it means that for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a constant $L = L(t)>0$ such that
$$ \left \vert f(t, y) - f(t, y') \right \vert \le L(t) \left \vert y-y' \right \vert$$
holds for every $y, y' \in \mathbb{R}^n$. That is, the functions
$$y \mapsto f(t, y), \ t\in\mathbb{R},$$
are Lipschitz continuous.

However, many sources simply state that $L$ is a constant, which gives the impression that it does not have a dependency on $t$, i.e., Lipschitz in $y$ would mean: exists a constant $L > 0$ such that
$$ \left \vert f(t, y) - f(t, y') \right \vert \le L \left \vert y-y' \right \vert$$
holds for every $y, y' \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

What is the correct definition?

Comment: For Lipschitz continuity in $y$, $L(t)$ can depend on $t$.

Comment: When $L$ is independent of $t$ we can say $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz ( uniform w.r.t. $t$).

Comment: In the proof found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Detailed_proof, isn't L treated as independent of t, although it is only said that f is Lipschitz in y?

Comment: As far as I know, for Picard-Lindelöf, the usual statement is indeed that $L(t)$ *does not* depend on $t$, so it must be "Lipschitz in $y$, uniformly in $t$". For example that's the statement given [here](https://zb260.user.srcf.net/notes/IB/anatop.pdf) and elsewhere in lecture notes online. Wikipedia isn't too clear about this, but it does assume this in its proof. There are functions which are Lipschitz in $y$ but not uniformly so - eg $|t|^{\frac 12} y$.

Comment: Is it actually formulated as being "Lipschitz in $y$" or the more usual "satisfies a Lipschitz condition in $y$" where then "Lipschitz condition" is defined as the above mentioned "uniformly Lipschitz in $y$".

Comment: The example I gave in my comment is silly! This is uniformly Lipschitz near $0$. A better example is something like $|t|^{\frac 14}(|y| + |t|^2)^{\frac 12}$ near $0$ (I think, anyway... the point being that when you fix $t$, it looks like a well-behaved part of $|y|^{\frac 12}$ slightly to the right of $0$, but it keeps sliding closer the the bad part, while also tending to $0$ when $t\to 0$). @LutzLehmann, the statement at the linked Wikipedia page says "Let $f:D\to \Bbb R^n$ be a function that is continuous in $t$ and Lipschitz continuous in $y$. Then ...", which I think is a bit confusing.